# Connect with RDP RemoteApp to a published app in Citrix XenApp?

Tags: rdp, remote-desktop-services, citrix, remoteapp, xenapp

Following [link](http://www.kreyman.de/index.php/microsoft/rdp-remotefx/8-citrix-vs-microsoft) shows a nice graphic about the architectural differences between Microsoft and Citrix.

Based to this graphic, is it possible to use **RDP RemoteApp** to **connect to** a published app in **Citrix XenApp**? Or use RDP to connect to a XenDesktop server?

If yes,

- does anyone have experience with this kind of constellation?
- are there any known limitations with connecting with RDP instead of Citrix ICA?
- what RDP parameters do I need to connect to a RemoteApp in Citrix XenApp or/and what do I have to configure in the XenApp?
- are there any web resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting to xenapp server using the remoteapp work, but you need to install the missing RDS's role correctly and to publish the app thru the RDS's console.

As you can guess you end up with two console. All the xenapp strategy (user or computer) will not be used as you use the rdp protocol.

For xendesktop you can rdp-in a VM, but if you have a streamed pool it will be illogical to do so. I used that tip for terminal that supported only rdp, but I needed a dedicated VM for the user. As keep in mind you bypass the desktop delivery controller that way, thus power-on, power-off, etc is all bypassed. (like xendesktop policy too). In the DDC the session will be flagged as non-brokered.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. So it's really neccessary to install and configure the missing RDS roles and publish the app through the RD Session Host service? This means, XenApp and/or XenDesktop only communicates with ICA protocol and can't be used either with RDP? 

I think I understand what you are meaning. If I would like to get access the VM pool  with RDP too, I need to install the missing RDS roles and configure an additional VM pool (not the same pool because XenDesktop and RD Virtualization Host will disturb each other if they use the same VM pool) on the server. Right?

Comment: @user1885888 yes, except for xendesktop part I just dedicated a vm and I hardcoded the machine name in the rdp link